# the numer p* is said to approximate p to t significant digits if t is the largest nonneative integer

Tags: numerical-methods

|p-p*|/|p|<=5*10^(-t)

said by numerical analysis textbook burden

then

how we define significant digits? do we have to choose any integer t?

example of this text book

p=0.54617, p*=0.5462 how we get significant digits by definition?

this text book say four significant digits but I don't know why

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  Your question is not clear at all.  Do you mean how do you get that $.54617$ to four significant figures $.5462$, or do you mean why has the book chosen to use four significant figures instead of say, three?

Comment: "this text book say four significant digits but I don't know why"  Because that's what the book wanted.  If I asked you to find $\pi$ to $2$ significant figures or to $17$ significant figures there wouldn't be any reason *why* I wanted those figures.  ... or maybe there would be a practical reason.  But there is no reason in general for *why* you choose $t$ to be $4$.  It's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

You take the largest $t$ that satisfies the requirement.  Just plug into the definition
$$\frac {|p^*-p|}p=\frac {|0.54617-0.5462|}{0.54617}=\frac{0.00003}{0.54617}\approx 0.000055$$
This is greater than $0.5\cdot 10^{-4}$, so it should only be $3$ significant digits.  Most people will just count the number of accurately rounded digits and say this has four, but that is not the definition you have quoted.

Comment: is this text book not correct? |p*-p|/|p|<=10^(-k)/2 largest k integer ?

Comment: 5,4,6 is significant digits?

Comment: For your first comment, see my calculation.  Do you understand it? Why did you change from $t$ to $k$, though that is not important?  Yes, the significant digits are $546$

Comment: significant digits is various definition each textbook .  can i accept your definition?

Comment: Yes, the definition varies.  You can use mine, but you may get marked down in this class.  Your book's definition tries to handle the glitch that happens when you change from a number about $99$ to one about $101$.  In my definition that adds one significant digit, but it really shouldn't.  I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227790/significant-digits/232934#232934) a while back.  [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280609/what-is-significance-of-in-significant-figures) has some more information